# How to avoid Azure Data Explorer table duplicates due to same parquet files in delta lake?

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-data-explorer, delta-lake

In Azure Synapse I have a Pipeline that read data and update a delta table when data change.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from delta.tables import DeltaTable

delta_table_path =abfss://test@adlstest.dfs.core.windows.net/db/tests'

table_exists = DeltaTable.isDeltaTable(spark, delta_table_path)

if table_exists:
    deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, delta_table_path) 
    deltaTable.alias("delta").merge(
        df_final.alias("updates"),
        "delta.Key= updates.Key") \
    .whenMatchedUpdate(
        condition = "delta.Value < updates.Value",
        set = {
        "Value": "updates.Value"
        }) \
    .whenNotMatchedInsertAll() \
    .execute()
else:
    (df_final.write.option("header", True)
                    .partitionBy("CITYID", "month")
                    .mode("append")
                    .format("delta")
                    .option("mergeSchema", "true")
                    .saveAsTable(f"{gold_database_name}.city")
                    )
```

Even if data doesn't change parquet files are created.

Problem is that I call this table in Azure Data Explorer:

```
.create external table TEST (CITYID: string, Key: string, Value: string)
kind=adl
dataformat=parquet
(
    h@'abfss://test@adlstest.dfs.core.windows.net/db/tests/CITYID1=A1;impersonate'
)
```

So it reads all parquet files corresponding to delta table and I see duplicates in ADX.

How can I avoid it ? In Synapse or ADX ?

I thought dropping table everytime code is executed, but maybe better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be using Materialized Views in ADX. The MVs are performing very well for deduplication. Unfortunately these views require a normal table instead of an external table. This means you would have two steps with

1. external_mydata -> your external table
2. mydata -> your table
3. mydata_view -> your Materialized view

*step1*
`.append mydata <| external_table('external_mydata') | where timestamp > lasttimestamp`

*step2*
`.create  materialized-view  with ( lookback=time(10.00:00:00),docString='my view')  mydata_view  on table   mydata { mydata    | summarize take_any(1) by  col1, col2, col3}`

For mydata, you could set the retention policy to a short amount of time. This minimizes your data volume and required performance:

```
`.alter-merge table mydata policy retention softdelete = 3d recoverability = disabled`
```

Not sure if there are currently better options available.